# SQL command - Incorrect syntax near 'String'

Tags: c#, sql

Can you tell me where this exception comes from? See code below where I try to put some values into SQL Database.

```
var cmd1 = new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO BoxTable (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, String, 19, 20, 21, 22) VALUES (@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17, @18, @String, @19, @20, @21, @22)");
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.Connection = connection;

            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@String", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = stringNum;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@1", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb1.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@2", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb2.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@3", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb3.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@4", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb4.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@5", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb5.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@6", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb6.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@7", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb7.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@8", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb8.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@9", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb9.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@10", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb10.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@11", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb11.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@12", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb12.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@13", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb13.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@14", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb14.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@15", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb15.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@16", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb16.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@17", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb17.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@18", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb18.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@19", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb19.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@20", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb20.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@21", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb21.Checked.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@22", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = cb22.Checked.ToString();
            connection.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
```

Comment: Copy and paste, and paste, and paste? Remove the duplicated text.

Comment: I guess "String" is not a valid column name? Maybe try "[String]".

Comment: You got column names from `1` to `21`? Ouch.

Comment: paste and paste because site engine said "your question is mostly code please add more details :/

Comment: Use self explained column names!

Comment: Ok apparently columns cannt be named with just digits. Changed to cb1, cb2 etc and it work now.